# Test a JDBC connection with JUnit and Mockito

Tags: java, testing, jdbc, junit, mockito

I am trying to write a unit test with JUnit5 and Mockito. I am still learning how to write test. The SUT is the class which establish the connection (using jdbc) to a PostgreSql DB.
I would like to test the logic of the class. Of course, I don't want to expose the real credentials in my test so I need to use some fake ones.

JDK 17
Postgres dependency : version 42.7.2, scope: compile

**SUT:**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class PostgresConnection {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(PostgresConnection.class);
    final String DATABASE ;
    final String USER;
    final String PASSWORD;

    public PostgresConnection() {
        this.DATABASE = ApplicationProperties.getPostgresDatabase();
        this.USER = ApplicationProperties.getPostgresUsername();
        this.PASSWORD = ApplicationProperties.getPostgresPassword();
    }

    public Connection connectionToDatabase () {

        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/" + DATABASE, USER, PASSWORD);

            if(connection != null) {
               LOGGER.info("Connected to Postgres database");
            } else {
                LOGGER.error("Connection to Postgres database failed");
            }
        } catch(SQLException e) {

            LOGGER.error("Error " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return connection;
    }


}
```

**the test class:**

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class PostgresConnectionTest {

    @Mock
    Connection mockConnection;

    @Mock
    Statement mockStatement;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

        // Mock the Connection and configure its behavior
        mockConnection = Mockito.mock(Connection.class);
        when(mockConnection.createStatement()).thenReturn(mockStatement);

        // Configure mock behavior for DriverManager.getConnection() to return the mockConnection
        when(DriverManager.getConnection(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString()))
                .thenReturn(mockConnection);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_postgresDatabaseConnection() throws SQLException {
        // Create PostgresConnection instance
        PostgresConnection postgresConnection = new PostgresConnection();
        Connection connection = postgresConnection.connectionToDatabase();

        assertNotNull(connection); // Assert that connection is not null


    }
}
```

The error I am having:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 

    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:706)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
    at ***.utils.PostgresConnectionTest.setUp(PostgresConnectionTest.java:46)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Mockito has a slightly different API for mocking static methods.

See [mockito mock static methods](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods)

```java
    PostgresConnection postgresConnection = new PostgresConnection();
    Connection connection;
    try (MockedStatic<DriverManager> mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(DriverManager.class)) {
        mockedStatic.when(() => DriverManager.getConnection(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(mockConnection)
        connection = postgresConnection.connectionToDatabase();
    }
    assertThat(connection).isNotNull();
```

Answer (score 0):

From a technical perspective, you *could* write such unit tests.
But as you state, you're currently learning to write unit tests, so from a conceptual perspective: Don't implement such tests.

Unit tests should test the *behavior* of your code. So, the use case you want to implement with your code. Obtaining an database connection is a technical step to fulfill the use case only. And such technical steps are usually not tested standalone.

For example, if your application is about creating blog posts:

**Unit tests** will check the behavior of your `BlogPost` objects and its business logic. Things like "Cannot create a blog post in the past", being check at the time a `BlogPost` instance will be created. This does usually not include any framework or infrastructure code (like connect to database).

**Integration tests** will check the behavior of the application itself, like "A user can create a blog post", which includes that the `BlogPost` is stored in database.
An integration test like this includes the creation of a database connection, since the test would fail if the blog post couldn't be saved due a connection error.

Another point is: If you test *every single technical step* in your application, you'll end up with tons of unit tests with mocks. That's hard to maintain and your tests will get brittle, meaning every time you'll change your code (due refactoring or new features) your tests could fail although your change didn't affected the use case itself.

If you need more conceptually input about how to write tests, I recommend Vladimir Khorikovs book "Unit Testing - Principles, Practices and Patterns". Helped me a lot to write reliable tests.